# X and Y to smooth destination

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I got 4 Variables:

```
X
Y

TargetX
TargetY
```

Basically `X and Y` are my start Point and I want to get to The Target.

I increase both `X and Y` til they get to their destination

Here is a photo:
[image: diagram]

I've done path `A` and want to do the smooth `B`
At the moment am I increasing each one. So how do I make both `X and Y` reach the `Destination` at the same Time 
(X and Y value is different!)
So simply make a shortcut.

//Tom

Comment: "I've done path A" - is that a broken-line path?

Comment: Please don't "sign" your posts; posts already include an identifier in the bottom right. If you want your name associated to your posts, then change the user name in your account to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

Compute the lengths of $A$ and $B$ and divide them into the same number of "steps".

Comment: So if my Start X and Y is 0
My Goal is 10,5
Then i have to??

Answer (score 1):

The way I'm reading your question, you want to move along a (single) straight line from $(X,Y)$ to $(\text{Target}X, \text{Target}Y)$. To do this, simply find the difference between the $x$-values and the $y$-values and divide those by the number of steps you want. Then you can add this number to your $X$ and $Y$ repeatedly. Here's a pseudocode example that should make things clearer.

```
X = whatever
Y = whatever
TargetX = whatever
TargetY = whatever

dx = TargetX-X
dy = TargetY-Y

numSteps = whatever

stepX = dx/numSteps
stepY = dy/numSteps

currentX = X
currentY = Y

for t = 0 to numSteps
{
currentX = X + t*stepX
currentY = Y + t*stepY
}
```

That help?